# Should Game Identification questions be tagged with the game name when an answer is found?

Tags: support, tags, game-identification

Someone else knowing this game could use the other ("wrong") answers as recommendations to similar games.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it would look a bit confusing how a question both asks about a game and lists it in the tags... it's a bit like editing the question to include the answer after it was found, I don't like it.

Answer (score 12):

No it should have an accepted answer, which would give that question a distinct color difference from the ones that don't have an answer

Answer (score 2):

Many [identify-this-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-game) questions will be the only question about that game, and the tag will end up deleted for lack of use.

Comment: I agree. If you already know the game's title, finding its game-identification post wouldn't be much use.

Comment: Note that Arqade's tags are [no longer removed](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5379/28182) if they are only used on one question