# Stop removing tags that are only used once in the last 6 months

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

One of the problems with the tagging system that are magnified on Arqade is the automatic tag removal script that removes tags that have only been used once in the last six months.

[There exists a simple setting to disable the tag removal scripts on SE sites](https://patents.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103/dont-expire-single-use-patent-number-tags#comment127_103). I propose to enable this setting and disable the automatic tag removal on this site. Of course bad tags are harmful, but having the community clean up [untagged](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) questions regularly that had their game tags removed is just a waste of time. I'm not convinced that the benefits of the script outweigh the harm and waste of time we know it causes.

As it is a simple setting there is no significant cost for SE to implement this. We, the Arqade community, bear the cost of changing this. We'll have to clean up more tags if I'm wrong about the benefit of the script, but I think the benefits will outweigh the harm by useless tags that won't get deleted. Other options might also be to implement better tools to deal with bad tags, making the automatic script obsolete.

I've proposed [a replacement for the script in form of a review queue for tags on Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148300/add-a-review-queue-for-new-and-for-rarely-used-tags), that should ensure that useless tags still get removed.

Comment: Is there a way to up vote this more than once?

Comment: Listing out the consequences would be useful to know too. What are our stats on actual useless tags that get auto-culled?

Comment: @Resorath We don't have that data, only SE has it. We can only observe the untagged questions.

Comment: I was about to share my meta post on Patents but I see you've found it

Comment: Funny, I proposed the exact same thing on scifi very early on. It didn't catch on, as far as I can tell. http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/885/automatic-tag-clean-up-and-the-long-tail

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Done.  Single-use tags will no longer be automatically cleaned up.

Get familiar with https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new - bogus new tags must now be removed diligently by editing.

Comment: woooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo

Comment: I think I speak on behalf of all on gaming when I say: I love you <3

Comment: Does this apply to other sites as well (like Board & Card Games)?

Comment: @bwarner no, it's a per-site setting

Comment: It's you. You're the awesome one.

Comment: @DavidFullerton Please turn off the tag killer on [scifi.se], [we've had that request up for a very long time](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/885/automatic-tag-clean-up-and-the-long-tail). I've also posted requests on other sites where the tag killer has been shown to cause harm.

Comment: IMO it would be better to require a tag wiki entry, or increase the interval to 12 months. I understand the rationale for Ask Patents, which is a unique site and case. This is a slippery slope for every other site; you can view the data behind the original 6 month rule at http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48418