# Rename the [legend-of-heroes-tits] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

I'm not sure but i think that the tag [legend-of-heroes-tits](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legend-of-heroes-tits) should have something else in it instead of 'tits' or am i just being overly sensitive?

The game name is Legend of Heroes: Trails in the Sky

Comment: Yes. (Ignore this part, comment box forces me to write more than 4 letters)

Comment: @MartinSojka thanks for agreeing- up vote next time ;)

Comment: Don't force me to *explain* the joke about answering "Yes." to an "A or B?" question ... ;)

Comment: @MartinSojka Must....not....post....trollface........

Comment: I admit, when I clicked, I was hoping for [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rRawOjP2Pbc)

Comment: It should be "TitS". No, wait..

Comment: @MartinSojka Try this:

Comment: Yes.​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ugh, that's not good. ಠ_ಠ

[We were discussing this in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6888096#6888096), and I've renamed it to [loh-trails-in-the-sky](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loh-trails-in-the-sky):

- XSEED Games, the people who published the game, seem to use [*LoH: Trails in the Sky*](http://xseedgames.com/forums/forumdisplay.php?7-LoH-Trails-in-the-Sky)
- Searching for "loh trails in the sky" in The Googles results in pretty much only that game
- It also turns out [that's what it was originally](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=4046980#4046980) before it was untagged as part of the ([now defunct](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5379/stop-removing-tags-that-are-only-used-once-in-the-last-6-months)) tag pruning job.