# Add a 'new tags' review queue

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, reviewing

[David](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3/david-fullerton) has kindly granted the request to [Stop removing tags that are only used once in the last 6 months](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5379/stop-removing-tags-that-are-only-used-once-in-the-last-6-months). In his answer he mentioned that we should:

> Get familiar with http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new - bogus new tags must now be removed diligently by editing.

Can we add this task to the review queues to make it easier for us to keep this on track?

Comment: This feature request will probably get more attention/success on [metase], since review queues are a network-wide thing.

Comment: @murgatroid99 The review queues can be configured on a per-site basis, as far as I know.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that. Either way, it would still probably get more attention on MSO and it is reasonably a network-wide change.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I already made that feature request [on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148300/add-a-review-queue-for-new-and-for-rarely-used-tags) almost two months ago.

Answer (score 1):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

The mod team recently reached out to the CM team to see if this was something that could be added as part of the [Review Queue overhaul](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346901/179041).

We were informed that the focus of that overhaul is to improve the review system in a way that makes the queues more flexible, but adding new queues is not something they can do as part of this. While we can expect some degree of customisation in future releases, it's unlikely that tag usage will be one of the areas we'll be able to add to review.