# Privileges: Create Tags page still says tags get deleted after 6 months

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

I'm aware that Arqade has disabled the automatic-tag-cleanup-after-6-months script (see [Stop removing tags that are only used once in the last 6 months](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5379/stop-removing-tags-that-are-only-used-once-in-the-last-6-months)), but the Privileges [Create Tags](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) sub-page still warns people that this happens.

I've (hopefully) illustrated this quite clearly in this picture:

[image: Yay for freehand circles!]

Comment: +1 for frowny face.

Comment: Please let me know if it isn't clear - I wouldn't want to cause any undue harm from misunderstanding :P

Comment: So wait, you've highlighted "moderator tools" in blue? That's what we're discussing here?

Comment: @Turtleweezard - there's always one person :-P

Comment: Not easily fixed. Privilege wikis can be edited with enough rep, but only on [metase] and all other sites pull from that. I don't think you can edit it on a per-site basis.

Comment: @lunboks - Hmm. that's a shame. maybe we can petition to get it changed to be similar to how the [closed/on hold](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) page gets the custom close reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As of July 13](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/66744/revisions), the master copy on MSO now reads (emphasis mine)

> **on some sites,** new tags will be automatically culled and removed from the system if they are not used by at least 1 other question in a 6 month period.

The change hasn't appeared on this site's page yet, but it should happen soon. This is probably the best we can do given all sites currently share the same set of privilege page.