# How should I tag a question about Universal Minecraft Editor?

Tags: support, tags

I have found a fix for Universal Minecraft Editor's broken chunk locator, and I wish to ask a question to provide information on how the fix works. This question is on-topic because it asks about game-specific utilities, listed in the help centre as a valid topic.

I am posting this question to allow [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/376578/250180) to continue to work, which has been since broken.

There is no tag for out-of-game utility third-party programs. How should this question be tagged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is about Universal Minecraft Editor, then tagging with [universal-minecraft-editor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/universal-minecraft-editor) would be fine.

We don't have an overarching "gaming utilities" tag, which wouldn't really group the software together in a meaningful way.

We already have plenty of software/utilities tags: [nvidia-geforce-experience](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nvidia-geforce-experience), [discord](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discord), [fraps](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fraps), not to mention all the PC storefronts: [steam](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steam), [ubisoft-connect](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ubisoft-connect), [gog](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gog) etc. So I see no problem with creating a
[universal-minecraft-editor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/universal-minecraft-editor) for that piece of software.

Comment: Thank you. Will the tag get deleted after 6 months if no one else posts another question?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 [Not on Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5379/28182)

Comment: Okay, done. It's [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/385425/250180).