# Why was the game specific tag removed from the Chrome dinosaur game identification question?

Tags: discussion

There are 3 questions related to the embedded dinosaur runner game that is shown whenever the Chrome browser is unable to connect to the internet:

1. [Name of Google Chrome dinosaur cactus game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/202171/37419)
2. [What is the name of the dinosaur in Google Chrome's 'no internet' game? [duplicate]](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/326400/37419)
3. [What's the deal with the cake in T-Rex Runner (Downasaur)?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/338755/37419)

As answered in the first question, the name of the game is "Downasaur".  We have a tag [downasaur](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/downasaur) with an excerpt as of [September 19](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/338760/2).

The tag has been added to all three questions.  However, it was removed from the first yesterday in [this edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/202171/5).  Am I missing a policy?  Why was the tag addition rolled back?  Should the tag be removed from the duplicate as well?

Comment: Conceptually, "what is the name of this thing" getting tagged with the name of the thing feels odd to me, but I can see where you're coming from here, and am not wholly opposed to it

Comment: @Unionhawk Looking at all the other [tag:game-identification] questions, most do not also have the associated game as a tag.  In fact, this question may actually be related, if not a duplicate of [Should identify-this-game questions be tagged with the game name when an answer is found?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/619/37419).  I am going to close since that seems to answer my question.